# How to deploy an openstack instance with ansible in a specific project

Tags: ansible, openstack

I've been trying to deploy an instance in openstack to a different project then my users default project. The only way to do this appears to be by passing the project_name within the `auth:` setting. This works fine, but is not really compatible with using a clouds.yaml config with the `clouds:` setting or even with using the admin-openrc.sh file that openstack provides. (The admin-openrc.sh appears to take precedence over any settings in `auth:`).

I'm using the current openstack.cloud collection 1.3.0 (https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/openstack/cloud/index.html). Some of the modules have the option to specify a `project:` like the network module, but the one server module does not.

So this deploys in a named project:

```
- name: Create instances
    server:
      state: present
      auth: 
        auth_url: "{{ auth_url}}"
        username: "{{ username }}"
        password: "{{ password }}"
        project_name: "{{ project }}"
        project_domain_name: "{{ domain_name }}"
        user_domain_name: "{{ domain_name }}"
      name: "test-instance-1"
      image: "{{ image_name }}"
      key_name: "{{ key_name }}"
      timeout: 200
      flavor: "{{ flavor }}"
      network: "{{ network }}"
```

When having sourced the admin-openrc.sh, this deploys only to your default project (OS_PROJECT_NAME=<project_name>

```
- name: Create instances
    server:
      state: present
      name: "test-instance-1"
      image: "{{ image_name }}"
      key_name: "{{ key_name }}"
      timeout: 200
      flavor: "{{ flavor }}"
      network: "{{ network }}
      image: "{{ image_name }}"
      key_name: "{{ key_name }}"
      timeout: 200
      flavor: "{{ flavor }}"
      network: "{{ network }}"
```

When I unset the OS_PROJECT_NAME, but set all other values from admin-openrc.sh, I can do this, but this requires to work with a non-default setting (unsetting the one enviromental variable:

```
- name: Create instances
    server:
      state: present
      auth: 
        project_name: "{{ project }}"
      name: "test-instance-1"
      image: "{{ image_name }}"
      key_name: "{{ key_name }}"
      timeout: 200
      flavor: "{{ flavor }}"
      network: "{{ network }}"
```

I'm looking for the most usefull way to use a specific authorization model (be it clouds.yaml or environmental variables) for all my openstack modules, while still being able to deploy to a specific project.

Comment: This may or may not be helpful, but I found that in many scenarios the project ID takes precedence over the project name. Does it work if you use `project_id` instead of `project_name`?

Answer (score 2):

*(You should upgrade to the last collection (1.5.3), or perhaps it is compatible with 1.3.0)*

You can use the `cloud` property from the
"server" task (openstack.cloud.server). Here is how you can proceed :

- All projects definitions are stored into `clouds.yml` (here is a part of its content)

```
clouds:
  tarantula:
    auth:
      auth_url: https://auth.cloud.myprovider.net/v3/
      project_name: tarantula
      project_id: the-id-of-my-project
      user_domain_name: Default
      project_domain_name: Default
      username: my-username
      password: my-password
    regions :
      - US
      - EU1
```

- from a task you can refer to the appropriate cloud like this

```
- name: Create instances
    server:
      state: present
      cloud: tarantula
      region_name: EU1
      name: "test-instance-1"
```

Answer (score 0):

We now refrain from using any environment variables and make sure the project id is set in the configuration of in the group_vars. This works because it does not depend on a local clouds.yml file. We basically build and auth object in Ansible that can be use thoughout the deployment